# DB2 10.1 EJB to RDB Mapping

Tags: jakarta-ee, db2, ejb, websphere

I am trying to generate the mapping table, currently for DB2 9.7, for an EJB 2.1 application running on IBM Websphere 8 for DB2 10.1.

The problem that I am facing is that apparently Websphere 8 doesn't support the generation of DB2 10.1 mappings
(https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS7JFU_8.5.5/com.ibm.etools.ejbbatchdeploy.doc/topics/regenc.html?cp=SS7JFU_8.5.5&lang=en under *-dbvendor name* )
I would normally use the ejbdeploy tool to generate it but only versions up to 9.8 are supported.

I tried to do the same using Rational Application Developer, and succeeded, only to find out that the Websphere doesn't like the produced outcome.
Note that according to the link even WAS 8.5.5, **the current version**, doesn't support DB2 10.1.

I am struggling to understand the logic behind this. Has IBM DB2 stopped supporting older applications? Can I just use the old 9.7 Map? So far the application seems to be working but I want to find a plausible explanation for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No IBM DB2 has not stopped supporting applications using earlier releases like 9.7.  Tools like the ejbdeploy tool are typically only updated at major release boundaries and at the time of the last WebSphere Application Server release, DB2 9.8 was the latest DB2 release.  All in-service versions of WebSphere Application Server support DB2 10.x and you should be able to use the mapping produced for DB2 9.7 without issues.